# "undo" is working in .inputrc but why is redo not

Tags: bash, inputrc

While "undo" is working in .inputrc the redo does not
as it is in an .inputrc:

```
# Control-Backspace is
"\b": undo

# Added to ensure it'd work:
"\e[1;3C": redo
```

But not. How to solve this ?

Comment: Neither `man 1 bash` nor `man 3readline readline` nor `bind -p` mentions `redo`. I haven't found it in the online documentation ([Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), [Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html)). `vi-redo` appears, although I don't know what it does nor what the connection to `redo` is, if any. Where did you get this `redo` from?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, `vi-redo` is vi's `.` which repeats the previous command.

Comment: You may be confusing with `zsh` which does have a `redo` widget.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I guess if I worked with vi(m) on a daily basis then I would know. Anyway, for now I think there is no such thing as `redo` in the context of the question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, note that it's not specific to `vim`. The original `vi` in the 70s already had that `.` == repeat command. I'd expect all `vi` implementations support it.